# matrix-vector form of a nonlinear system

Tags: matrices, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I have the following system where $k = 0,1,..., N-1$, $j = 0,1,...,n$ and $v$ is a constant

$u_k^{j+1} = u_k^j - v (u_k^j)^2 + v u_k^j u_{k-1}^j$

and I would like to write this in matrix-vector form if possible.

I have tried to do this myself but I have the term $u_k^j$ appearing in the matrix.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the formula for $u_0^{j+1}$?

Comment: And by the way, you can't write it in vector form (without tensor operations) because $(u_k)^2$ is basis dependent. Why don't you like your equation as it is?

Comment: $u_k^{j+1} = u(k\Delta x, j\Delta t)$ is the numerical approximation of $u(x,t)$ at point $(k\Delta x, j\Delta t)$ in the inviscid Burger's equation. All I know about $u_0^{j+1}$ is that it is equal to $u_N^{j+1}$ as the system is periodic.

Comment: I would like the equation in the form $\mathbf{U}^{j} = \mathbf{A}_j \mathbf{U}^{j-1}$ if possible so that I can analyse the properties of $\mathbf{A}_j$.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a bilinear form, i.e.

$$
\mathbf{U}^{j+1} = \mathbf{U}^{j} - (\mathbf{U}^{j})^T B \, \mathbf{U}^{j} 
$$
with
$$
B = v \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & \ddots & 1 & -1 \\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

If that helps you with your particular problem depends on the question you want to answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like the equation in the form $\mathbf{U}^{j} = \mathbf{A}_j \mathbf{U}^{j-1}$ if possible so that I can analyse the properties of $\mathbf{A}_j$. The equation in my question is obtained using an upwind scheme for the inviscid Burger's equation where $v = \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}$.

Comment: It is impossible to put it into the form like that. As other comments pointed out already.
You might could look at a linearisation of the problem around a specific state.
For Burger's equation, if we fix a state $u_0(x)$, then we get something like $\partial_t u = - u_0 \partial_x u - u \partial_x u_0 = -\partial_x( u \cdot u_0 )$.
(I hope I didn't messed up the signs! Don't trust me.) 
The corresponding upwind linearisation is of course linear, as you wished.
But it only reflects the behaviour locally! 

However, for Burger's equation, there are maybe better ways to analyse it?